# Methods to use to gather statistical datas with capacities of web server

Tags: java, networking, load, webserver, ddos

I'm  trying to make a simulation tool for load balancing with web servers. So the basic parameters that our system can handle with web servers are the maximum load that a specific server that can handle. So to simulate such specific server, I need to be able to DDOS a web server that I've set up and then gather some data in response to its CPU & RAM usage (our simulation system will also be able to provide these data between JSP and PHP Servers).

How can I come up with a model so that I can code it? Probably the stuffs like maximum requests that a certain web server can handle.

Answer (score 0):

A way to test the maximum load is to us Jmeter http://jmeter.apache.org/

It is quite easy to test some simple things. However if you want to load test the server you need to make sure that the client you are using doesn't become the limiting factor. So check the resources (cpu, memory, network) regularly. Jmeter also has the ability to synchronize test from more than one computer.

Jmeter also supports data gathering and has some nice graphs out of the box :-).

Comment: what is the ideal ramp-up period for testing php and jsp web servers? Im trying to do some testing now. And it seems i can see the results using the task manager in the server computer. Can the jmeter provide me some statistical data specifically the cpu and ram usage of my target server?

Comment: You can get the cpu and ram usage if your servlet environment uses JMX. check http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-monitor-test-plan.html